# I've got a Pandas DF using Date as an index, it has data from 2017-01-01 to 2019-31-12. How can I drop all rows that have the year 2019 in them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Deleting all the columns of date which contain 2019 in the index data from 2017-2019

```py
df_raw1 = df_raw1.drop(index=['2019'])
```

Error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15244\372933074.py in <module>
----> 1 df_raw1 = df_raw1.drop(index=['2019'])


KeyError: "['2019'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. It will help if you can provide dataframe example. Without this it is impossible to send an accurate answer.

Comment: I have meteorological data from 2017-01-01 to 2019-12-31, but i only need data from 2017-2018, I need to drop all the values for the year 2019.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and actually include a sample of your data so we can see the names of your index/columns and format of values. Just run `df_raw1.head(10).to_dict()`, for example. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no example dataset, so I am gonna guess the date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` or `2017-01-01`. Also it's not clear, whether the date is **column name** or rather **row value**.

I would use

```py
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('2019')]
```

or

```py
df = df.drop(df.filter(regex='2019').columns, axis=1)
```